# How do i transform a number to a repetition of characters in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, mediawiki, freemind

I have the following input:

```
<node TEXT="txt">
  <node TEXT="txt">
    <node TEXT="txt"/>
    <node TEXT="txt"/>
  </node>
  <node TEXT="txt"/>
</node>
<node TEXT="txt"/>
```

I am currently using:

```
<xsl:number level="multiple" count="node" format="1"/>
```

within an XSTL script to receive the following output:

```
1 txt
1.1 txt
1.1.1 txt
1.1.2 txt
1.2 txt
2 txt
```

but i want to have this output:

```
* txt
** txt
*** txt
*** txt
** txt
* txt
```

Can you help me?

PS: I want to convert a freemind map to basic mediawiki list syntax. And yes! i am aware that there are several ways to get native freemind maps into media wikis, but i need the conversion of the `<node>`-tree to `***`-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to just translate the result of the

```
<xsl:number/>
```

into the wanted format.

This transformation:

`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

`<xsl:output method="text"/>`

`<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`

```
<xsl:template match="node">
  <xsl:variable name="vIndent">
    <xsl:number level="multiple" count="node"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(translate($vIndent,
                     '1234567890.',
                     '**********'),
           ' ',
           @TEXT,
         '&#xA;'
         )"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

`</xsl:stylesheet>`

when applied on this XML document:

```
<t>
    <node TEXT="txt">
        <node TEXT="txt">
            <node TEXT="txt"/>
            <node TEXT="txt"/></node>
        <node TEXT="txt"/></node>
    <node TEXT="txt"/>
</t>
```

produces the wanted result:

```
* txt
** txt
*** txt
*** txt
** txt
* txt
```

Note the use of the translate() function to discard any "." characters and to translate any digit into an "*".